# correlation not found in Cluster Analysis in r

Tags: r, cluster-computing, correlation

here is the dataset I am working on, from the link: https://worldhappiness.report/ed/2022/
file name: Data_for_Figure_2.1

I am trying to find how the variables correlate in a correlation map, the code was written as below

```
corr <- cor(happy22[, 3:8], method = "pearson")
ggplot(melt(corr, varnames = c("x", "y"), value.name = "correlation"),
aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_tile(aes(fill = correlation)) +
scale_fill_gradient2(
low = "green",
mid = "yellow",
high = "red",
guide = guide_colorbar(ticks = FALSE, barheight = 5),
limits = c(-1, 1)
) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
labs(title = "Heatmap of correlation matrix",
x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

the error shows:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'correlation' not found
In addition: Warning messages:

    1: In type.convert.default(X[[i]], ...) :
      'as.is' should be specified by the caller; using TRUE
    2: In type.convert.default(X[[i]], ...) :
      'as.is' should be specified by the caller; using TRUE
```

I cant figure out what this means, why 'correlation' not found? where is 'as.is' in my code?
Could anyone please help?

Comment: How did you import the data? The Data for Figure 2.1 is not a set of independent variables for measuring "happiness" but a set of variables based on "happiness". The error message you show seems to relate to the "fill=correlation" part of your code where you have not created/defined a object called "correlation".

Comment: I added them through 'import dataset' --'from excel', any problem?

Comment: It is strange that one time I ran it the error shows the above, another time it shows 'could not find function "melt"', another time it shows 'could not find function "ggplot"'.. while I did not change anything, and I have installed all the packages.

Comment: But you need to load the packages using the `library()` function. Installing them is not enough. Your code does not show any packages loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to replicate your error when I used `melt()` in the package reshape. Just FYI reshape has been superseded by the suite of tidyverse packages a few years ago which I highly recommend switching to (https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/). In the tidyverse you would use the function `pivot_longer()` instead of `melt()`.

If you run `melt(corr, varnames = c("x", "y"), value.name = "correlation")` on its own, you'll notice there is no resulting column called `correlation` and that is why `ggplot` isn't able to find it. The `value.name` argument is from reshape2, the package that superseded the package you used. So, you could either manually rename your 3rd column, switch to `melt` in reshape2 or switch to the tidyverse, which I would recommend. Here is the same logic using `pivot_longer()` from the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
corr <- cor(happy22[, 3:8], method = "pearson",
            use = "complete.obs")
corr %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column('x') %>% 
  pivot_longer(-x,
               names_to = 'y',
               values_to = 'correlation') %>% 
  ggplot(.,
         aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = correlation)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = "green",
    mid = "yellow",
    high = "red",
    guide = guide_colorbar(ticks = FALSE, barheight = 5),
    limits = c(-1, 1)
    ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(title = "Heatmap of correlation matrix",
       x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image: corr ggplot]